# Why past tense for unreal present?

Tags: past-tense, conditionals, reason-why

I was wondering why exactly past tense is used in the unreal present conditional (type 2).

I once heard that past tense gives a sense of "distance" when contrasted with present, but I'm not sure if this is the sole reason behind this grammatical peculiarity.

Does anyone have a different explanation on this?

Comment: ***Present*** means ***here**, at this location* as well as ***now**, at this time*. Things which are "here and now" are *by definition* "real", so we naturally avoid using Present Tense to refer to things which are "unreal, counterfactual". The difference between #1 *If he **loved** you he **would** marry you* and #2 *If he **loves** you he **will** marry you* is basically down to "degree of uncertainty" (speaker in #1 thinks he ***doesn't*** love you, whereas speaker in #2 thinks he ***might***).

Answer (score 1):

In CoGEL  this use  of the past tense is being referred to as "*the hypothetical past*".

> (**CoGEL § 4.16**) (c) The HYPOTHETICAL PAST is used in certain subordinate clauses, especially if-clauses, and expresses what is contrary to the belief or expectation of the speaker:
>
> - If you really worked hard, you would soon get promoted.  **[1]**
> - It's time we all took a rest. **[2]**
> - I wish I had a memory like yours. **[3]**
>
> The hypothetical past, as in [1-3], implies the nonoccurrence of some
> state or event in the present or future. The implication of [1], for example,
> is that the hearer does not work hard.

Comment: I perfectly understand WHEN it's used, but I just wanted to know WHY the past (what the reasoning behind this kind of usage is).

Comment: @AllenZ — Why indeed! You think language develops by logical reasoning? All you can reasonably ask is HOW it developed, pointing the difference from the Germanic and Romance languages that contributed to modern English. But if you did that, you would need to show you had done a little research of your own first, as an answer would be an extensive undertaking. You didn’t really think it was simple?

Comment: CoGel? You don’t really think a new user who hasn’t even mastered the use of articles in English would have any idea of what that is? I certainly haven’t. Rule 1 of communication — don’t use abbreviations unless you have to, and if you have to define them.

Comment: Not to be called "subjunctive", of course.

Comment: @David It is a long title to write, and  I find myself having to do that repetitively;  so I figure  that if  the reader is curious enough he/she'll  ask about it. If not, he/she'll  still get  the  notion that a serious reference has been used for the answer. For your personal information, I use "CoGEL" for "_A Comprehensive Grammar of  the English Language_", (1985 edition, Quirk &  al.), not to be  confused with CGEL (the  _standard_  abbreviation for "_The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language_", Huddleston & Pullum).

Comment: @LPH — The choice is yours. Communicate with people or exclude them.

Comment: @JohnLawler The difference can be seen in this pair, I believe: "If he was willing there  would be nothing to stop him. (He is  not willing)/"If he were willing there  would be nothing to stop him. (He might be willing or  he might not)".

Comment: @LPH They both sound counterfactual to me; _was_ is more common than _were_ in this construction, I think, except in fixed phrases like _Wish you were here_.

Comment: @JohnLawler  This is in fact what can be concluded; there is no difference in either variant of the language; "_was_" is  merely less formal (CoGEL); so the opposition  I suspected does not exist. However, "_was_" is still said to be a form of  the indicative, a  fact, as I understand  now, that you seem to find nonsensical.

Comment: There's no moods in English, subjunctive or indicative. _Was_ is the first person and third person singular past tense form of the auxiliary verb _be_. It is as indicative as it is subjunctive.